# DENSE-RANK to rank the department with most employees

Tags: sql, mysql, rank

I have a table called employees with follow column:

| Field | Type | NULL | Key |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| employee_id | int | NO | PRI |
| first_name | varchar(20) | YES |  |
| last_name | varchar(25) | NO |  |
| email | varchar(100) | NO |  |
| phone_number | varchar(20) | YES |  |
| hire_date | date | NO |  |
| job_id | int | NO | MUL |
| salary | decimal(8,2) | NO |  |
| manager_id | int | YES | MUL |
| department_id | int | YES | MUL |

I want to rank the department with most employees, here was my query:

```
SELECT department_id, COUNT(employee_id) no_employee, 
    DENSE_RANK() 
    OVER (PARTITION BY department_id 
    ORDER BY COUNT(employee_id) DESC ) Rank_ 
FROM employees 
GROUP BY department_id;
```

However, the result gave back rank all the departments "1", no matter how much employees they had, like below:

| department_id | no_employee | Rank_ |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 6 | 1 |

At first, I did not add the GROUP BY operator in the query, but then the system showed error of non-aggragate column.

Can someone help me with this?

I expect the result will be like this (the data may not be correct)

| department_id | no_employee | Rank_ |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 1 |
| 2 | 9 | 2 |
| 3 | 8 | 3 |

Answer (score 0):

Remove the partition by clause and rank

```
SELECT department_id, COUNT(employee_id) no_employee, 
    RANK() OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(employee_id) DESC ) Rank_ 
FROM employees 
GROUP BY department_id;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/d227UwOW

Comment: Oh, it works, thanks a lot ^^! May I ask why I cannot use PARTITION BY operator in this case?

Comment: Order of execution , aggregation then rank